# Inconsistent score adding when killing enemy

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm making an Asteroid Destroyer game in which you get score as time passes by (the game becomes progressively more difficult), but also when you hit an asteroid. I have written a method inside the `Game1` class to calculate the amount of score that should be added by the end of the `Update` method.

The code is as follows:

```
private float CountScore(GameTime gameTime, List<Asteroid> asteroids)
{
    float addScore = 0;
    foreach (Asteroid asteroid in asteroids)
    {
        if (asteroid.Killed)
        {
            addScore += 100;
        }
    }

    if (spaceship1.Alive)
    {
        addScore += 80 * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }

    return addScore;
}
```

The method is called like this in the `Update` method:

```
score += CountScore(gameTime, asteroids);
```

The part of the code that adds score as time passes works fine. The problem is that when I destroy an asteroid, instead of getting 100 more score points, sometimes I get 200, sometimes I get 2000 and sometimes I get 5000. I don't understand what is happening, since only asteroids that are killed by the player get the property `Killed = true;`, so I don't really think it is adding 100 per asteroid on screen.

Does anybody know what could cause this? If it's needed I can post more code, but I didn't want to write too much here for the sake of readability.

Edit:
Adding `asteroid.Killed = false;` just after adding the score worked. However I still don't understand what was the issue, since it looks like it was looping through the same asteroid more than once.

Comment: I don't see that you are removing the processed asteroid from `asteroids` list, so maybe you are adding 100 points for each asteroid destroyed,

Comment: Unless the asteroids are being removed elsewhere in the program, it looks like killed asteroids are just piling up in the list and giving 100 points each time another asteroid gets killed. Note that if you remove the killed asteroids from the list in that function, you'll need to do it in a separate loop, as you aren't allowed to modify a collection while enumerating it with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: When an asteroid is killed, the `bool` property `Killed` is changed to true, property which all new asteroids have set as false. Also, I'm not removing them from the list since I reuse `Killed` asteroids (giving them a new position and setting `Killed` to false again. I also should note that sometimes the first asteroid killed in the current game gives 5000 or more score points.

Comment: @Nordellak then, instead of a bool for killed, you may need another type of variable,an int for example , for alive,killed and killed and processed. I doubt that the first asteroid killed would give 5000 points with this code, unless you are calling the method multiple times, and using an int property for `killed` would also solve it

Comment: @Pikoh I tried to change the code so that `asteroid.Killed` is set to false after adding the score and it worked. I still don't understand why it doesn't work the other way around; it's as if it looped through that same asteroid more than once. Thanks for your hint nevertheless ;)

Comment: It's easy to understand. With the first killed asteroid, in your list you have one asteroid with killed=true. With the second, you already have 2 killed=true. So, in your `foreach (asteroid in asteroids)` you'll add points twice. And so on

Comment: Okay, now I get it. It was adding 100 every game loop until the said killed asteroid was reused again. This is why sometimes I got 5000 points out of one single asteroid, because I guess more time passed before it was reused. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway,there's no point in reuse asteroids. I would just remove the killed asteroids once the points are added,and create new asteroids when needed.

Comment: I read in a tutorial for projectiles that removing and adding objects is more resource expensive than leaving them hidden and reusing them as needed. I don't know how expensive is to create and remove an object, but it makes sense, so if there will be only 50 asteroids on screen at a given point of time, there will be 50 already created asteroids that just change their fields and properties as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that the logic for adding to the score when an asteroid is killed, is done at the same time as the logic for killing an asteroid.

It is likely that you are iterating through the list of asteroids already when processing the hit detection, and thus it would improve performance if the logic was done at the same time, instead of having another foreach loop, as demonstrated in your code.

Further more your addScore += 80 * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; is unreliable, a player with a higher FPS will have an unfair advantage. I recommend using the deltaTime when adding to the total score during the games progression.

Comment: Before writing this method, the score adding logic was done just after checking for the asteroid killing, in the same foreach loop, and I had the same problem. I tried to do it in a separate method in case it was a problem with doing it at the same time.
Regarding the score increasing as time passes, what is the deltaTime exactly? I have never heard of it

Comment: deltaTime is the time between the last frame, and the current frame - Therefore the amount of time start has passed since the last time you ran the game loop. At a constant 60 FPS, delta time would be ~ 0.01667. Whereas 30 fps would be ~ 0.334

given 80 * deltaTime, after 1 complete second, the player will be awarded 80 additional points

Comment: After looking at the docs it seems gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds is in fact the deltaTime, so please ignore that comment

Comment: (I am too noob to reply to comments, so regarding your removing/adding object comment above... I agree that reusing objects where possible is much better than removing them and re-adding them, however it would be better if you moved any unused objects to a new list.

i.e.
List<Asteroid> asteroids # Active asteroids
List<Asteroid> recycleroids # Inactive (killed) asteroids, awaiting recycling